# would the following code cause performance issues in my game loop

Tags: android, optimization, android-view

I have a game loop which is constantly being called to update the game. Inside that loop is the following code:

```
mySurfaceView.post(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                myView.setTranslationX(myCam.getX());
                myView.setTranslationY(myCam.getY());

            }
        });
```

I've been told that putting the "new" keyword in my game loops is usually not a good idea because memory is constantly being allocated to new objects. However this is an anonymous inner class so I'm not sure if the same applies here. Would this code cause performance issues? And if so, then how would I go about solving them? I use this code to make my the screen be oriented around my player when he moves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach would be to send a message to a Handler on the UI thread, rather than posting a Runnable.  This is easiest if your translation X/Y values are integers.

For an example, see the way ActivityHandler is used in the "record GL app" activity in [Grafika](https://github.com/google/grafika/blob/master/src/com/android/grafika/RecordFBOActivity.java).  The UI thread creates a new Handler and passes it to the renderer thread, which sends messages to it.  `handleUpdateFps()` is a good example, as it's passing a pair of integers to the UI thread.

If you can't pass the values as fixed-point, you have to pass them through an Object, and things start to get complicated.  Overall this approach is more involved than simply posting a Runnable.

(A better approach would be to adjust your coordinates internally, having a notion of "world space" vs. "screen space", and not mess with the View's values. But looking at your other questions, you tried that approach and were not successful.)

Comment: luckily I just figured out my problem was that I was not adjusting my TouchListener's x and y values properly so I won't be needing to mess with the View anymore. Nevertheless check and up vote for you my good sir. Also I never got the yes or no answer for whether or not the above code would cause performance issues? I'm guessing yes?

Comment: It's best to avoid allocations in the game loop, because the VM will need to collect garbage occasionally. The garbage collector has improved over the years, so you won't get 100ms hiccups like Android 1.0 had, but collecting garbage is always more expensive than not collecting garbage.